# Typescript: number type can be assigned to string type using Omit, Optional, Intersection Types

Tags: typescript, types

Could you please tell me why the following code does not cause an error?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwEYQE4BVzQLxQN4CwAUFFAGYCWEANgCYD8AXPlBbcwM7CoUB2A5gG4ovRClQB5VAGVuffkxFi0UAL6Di64qEhRZPAZl24JCCsAA88ZGiMQANFABElGrScA+KADJ8xUq50inis7FBcBvxqPiyiNpIycgKKEfJqGkRaRMQAxgD2vFxQwBBFuAAUHMz68nYAlFDYXoQkUPmFwCLM1uJ2jeHCAPSDInlQaKh5qJoZxEA)

```
type NumberType = {
  field?: { id: string; numberOrString?: number }
};
type StringType = Omit<NumberType, "field"> & {
  field?: { id: string } & { numberOrString?: string }
};

const test = (s: StringType) => {
  // `numberOrString?: number` can be assigned to `numberOrString?: string`
  const n: NumberType = s; // no error
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in TypeScript, see [microsoft/TypeScript#19927](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19927).

Your `Omit<NumberType, "field">` type evaluates to the equivalent of `{[K in never]: ...}`, and apparently intersections of such `never`-keyed mapped types and other object types with optional properties are not checked correctly.  This bug has been open for a long time so it's not clear when or even if it will be fixed; presumably people don't run into it very often?  If you care a lot you might want to give that issue a  or describe your actual use case, but I don't know if it will have any effect.

Comment: Thank you for your very quick reply.
And exactly what I wanted to know.
Thank you very much!